# C++ overload [][] for a list

Tags: c++, list, operator-overloading

I got a `class Matrix` with a member `std::list<Element> listMatrix;`. `Element` is a a class with 3 `int` members `line, column, value`. I save in the list, elements of a matrix that are not 0 by saving the line, column and the value of the respectively element. I want to overload the `operator [][]` so I can do something like `Matrix a;` `a[2][3] = 5;`. I know you can't `overload [][]` directly.

Comment: ot: is there any reason you use a `list` ? a `vector` is very likely much faster due to locality of the data (ie less chache misses). And I wouldnt exect a matrix to insert elements in the middle that often...

Comment: I need to use ```list``` because the problem specifies that you need to use a list.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I guess this is a sparse matrix format

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do overload `Element& operator()(int, int)` (and the `const` variant) so you can write

```
matrix(2, 3) = 5;
```

If you *absolutely* need the `[2][3]` syntax, you'd need to define a proxy class so `matrix[2]` return a  proxy value and `proxy[3]` return the desired reference. But it comes with a lot of problems. The basic idea would be:

```
class naive_matrix_2x2
{
    int data[4];

    struct proxy
    {
          naive_matrix_2x2& matrix;
          int x;
          int& operator[](int y) { return matrix.data[x*2+y]; }
    };
public:
    proxy operator[](int x) { return {*this, x}; }
};
```

Full demo: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd053610e56692f6

Comment: I need to do it like ```[2][3]```. I read in other questions about a proxy class but didn't understood how it works and how should I implement one. Is there a better in depth or a longer explication about this and how can I solve the problems that comes with it ? Edit: Also another problem that comes with the overload [][], after I overload the [][] and I write ```matrix[2][3] = 0``` is it possible to make it so it deletes the element ```(2,3,value)``` from the list, because it becomes 0 and I have in list only elements that are not 0.

Comment: I think you overcomplicate things. This would need a second layer of proxy to detect when 0 is written (by overloading `operator=`. Not A Good Idea (tm).

Comment: I see. I know but I'm just trying to take in account all the cases possible. I will do it like this for the moment, thanks for the answer

Comment: You might as well give the proxy a real name - `class Row` is how I named mine.

Comment: @OvidiuFirescu: The term for such implementations is a _sparse matrix_. I would first consider not writing to a sparse matrix; instead I'd implement initialization of a sparse matrix with a regular matrix. In this operation you just copy the non-zero elements. But if your matrices are so sparse that this takes too much memory, then I'd re-implement the underlying operation not to use row/column access at all.

Comment: I saw, @lisyarus also mentionating that this is a sparse matrix didn't know that's how is named. I got functions for initialization, adding 2 matrix, multiplying 2 matrix, modifying a element, copy construct, overload operator=, the overload of the [][] was the last task I need to do for this problem, and I really didn't know how to start or how to do it.

Comment: This is a smart solution. Having multiple dimension matrix defined as 1 dimension is great for jumping around the matrix and for memory management. I would just suggest to the OP of this question to supply the answer with additional , index from row/column/height formula so that people can understand easier how matrix(a,b,c... ) works.

Answer (score 4):

The list is not a suitable container for using the subscript operator because it has no direct access to its elements without moving an iterator through the list.

So the operator will be inefficient.

It is better to use the standard container `std::vector` that already has the subscript operator.

Nevertheless answering your question the operator can be defined the following way. You can add to the operators an exception then an index will point outside the list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

struct A
{
    int x, y, z;
    int & operator []( size_t n ) 
    {
        return n == 0 ? x : n == 1 ? y : z;             
    }

    const int & operator []( size_t n ) const
    {
        return n == 0 ? x : n == 1 ? y : z;             
    }
};

struct B
{
    std::list<A> lst;
    A & operator []( size_t n )
    {
        auto it = std::begin( lst );
        for ( ; n; n-- ) std::advance( it, 1 ); 
        return *it;
    }

    const A & operator []( size_t n ) const
    {
        auto it = std::begin( lst );
        for ( ; n; n-- ) std::advance( it, 1 ); 
        return *it;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b = { { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } } };

    std::cout << b[0][0] << '\n';
    std::cout << b[0][1] << '\n'; 
    std::cout << b[0][2] << '\n'; 

    b[2][1] += 20;

    std::cout << b[2][1] << '\n'; 
}
```

The program output is

```
1
2
3
28
```

Comment: I know the list is not a suitable, but I need to use it. Also, the program doesn't work like the way I need in my problem. For your example, you have only 3 elements in your list ```b[1][2] b[4][5] b[7][8]``` and the output for this three elements should be ```3 6 9```, the rest of the elements should be 0 because they are not in the list. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Ovidiu Firescu I showed how the operator can be defined. You can use the example as a base for your operator overloading. What you are describing in the comment does not relate to your question.

Comment: I see, was a good example for understanding how to implement the [][] for a list, thanks